# Travelling within US as an international student without a passport and with a child

Tags: usa, air-travel, passports, paperwork

My wife, my 5 year old child, and I would be flying to San Francisco for our German visa. At the consulate, our passports would be collected. My question is how do I fly back with our passports taken? My wife and I have driver license. I guess that might work. But my concern is that we wouldn't have any ID for our child. We would have her birth certificate but since it is not a US birth certificate I am not sure how much stock to put into it. Has anyone had any experience with something similar? I am planning to take copies of all our documents, like passport and visa. Would that help? Any suggestions?

Additional Information: I have Oregon's driver license whereas my wife has a learner's permit. We are flying Alaska from San Francisco.

I was wondering if talking to the TSA when we land there and tell them about our conundrum might be helpful or would that be an exercise in futility?

Final Update: Thank you everyone for your opinions and suggestions. In the end having the driver's license and permit sufficed. I was also ready with bank cards as well as copy of the passports for all of us, but it was not needed.

Comment: Is it a US or Canadian driver's license? If not, TSA is not going to accept it.

Comment: You don't say where you live while in the US. If you're in California and want ID for your child you can get the child a [non-driver ID](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/driver-licenses-identification-cards/identification-id-cards/).

Comment: ...Why are they taking away your passports?

Comment: @Vikki for stamping post checking my documents I assume

Comment: @user5803465: In that case, wouldn't they give them back as soon as they stamped them, making the question of travelling domestically as an international student without a passport moot?

Comment: Does your wife have a non-driver ID?

Comment: @Vikki they probably need a few weeks to process the application.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Flying to and from San Francisco from where?  Alaska?  Canada?  Europe?

Comment: @gerrit the question says (in the next to last paragraph) that they're flying to Alaska from San Francisco.  It doesn't say where they're flying from to San Francisco, but since they'll have their passports at that point there will certainly be no concern about having sufficient identification.

Comment: user5803465 I just saw the information about the learner's permit.  I've added a paragraph to the answer.

Comment: @phoog It says they're flying "Alaska", which can either mean the state or the airline (without the pronoun, I would be more inclined to interpret it as the airline).

Comment: @gerrit you're absolutely right.  I did not consider that possibility, but it's actually the more likely meaning.  (I had assumed that the preposition "to" had been omitted in error.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> my concern is that we wouldn't have any ID for our child.

Children under the age of 18 years do not need to show ID to pass the TSA checkpoint:

> Adult passengers 18 and older must show valid identification at the airport checkpoint in order to travel.

https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification

This leaves the airline's ID requirements, but you haven't mentioned which airline.  As an example, United:

> Children under the age of 18 traveling with an adult are not required to show ID at time of check-in.

https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/id/travel.html

In an edit, you note that your wife has only a learner's permit.  If it's a photo document that resembles a driver's license, it should be ok.  Otherwise, your wife may have trouble and it might indeed be a good idea to check with TSA about that.  Another possibility is to ask whether the consulate can allow her to retain her passport for the flight home and then send it to the consulate by mail or courier.  Finally, TSA has a procedure for identifying travelers who have lost or forgotten their identification document; my wife (a foreign resident of the US in nonimmigrant status) did this several years ago; it basically consisted of giving them her bank cards whereafter they asked her about various facts that they checked against her credit report.  It took a bit longer than usual, of course, but the additional time needed was fairly reasonable.

Comment: how do they know one is under 18 if they don't show an ID?

Comment: @njzk2 I suppose TSA would just have to take the accompanying adult's word for it.  In any event, I can imagine that that question would arise in some cases, but 
surely not here.

Comment: @njzk2 - several times my (tall for his age) son was asked how old he was before he got his Real ID drivers license at 15. He was travelling with us, and they took his word.